# Как убрать видимую область панели с информацией, меню акордеона, если есть свойство padding, на JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, accordion

Решил написать свой код для меню акордеона, возможно код далеко не идеален, прошу не придираться, я только учусь. Вроде как все работает, но есть одно но. Панель с ифнормацией полностью не скрывается из-за padding свойства (фон видно всегда), как можно это исправить.

Для лучшего понимания проблемы, [вот ссылка на проект](https://plupiks.github.io/menu-acordeon/).

```js
let acordeon = document.querySelector("#acordeon");
let panel = document.querySelector("#panel");

acordeon.addEventListener('click', function () {
  this.classList.toggle('active');
  slideDown();
});

function slideDown() {
  if (panel.style.maxHeight == 0) {
    panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
  } else {
    panel.style.maxHeight = null;
  }
}
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.acordeon {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.active,
.acordeon:hover {
  background-color: rgb(253, 253, 253);
}

.acordeon::after {
  color: #777;
  content: "\002b";
  font-size: 25px;
  float: right;
}

.active::after {
  content: "\2212";
  color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
}

.panel {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: azure;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Acordeon menu</h1>
<button id="acordeon" class="acordeon"></button>
<div id="panel" class="panel">
  <p class="panel--text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ex, architecto dolorem aut molestias aliquam vel fuga repudiandae in labore nobis ut
    eius quasi omnis, ducimus blanditiis placeat sapiente dolore possimus!
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Просто убери верхний и нижний отступ `.panel { padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;`

Comment: понял, спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы и так добавляете класс `active`, можно и к нему привязаться

```js
let acordeon = document.querySelector("#acordeon");
let panel = document.querySelector("#panel");

acordeon.addEventListener('click', function () {
  this.classList.toggle('active');
  slideDown();
});

function slideDown() {
  if (panel.style.maxHeight == 0) {
    panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
  } else {
    panel.style.maxHeight = null;
  }
}
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.acordeon {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.active,
.acordeon:hover {
  background-color: rgb(253, 253, 253);
}

.acordeon::after {
  color: #777;
  content: "\002b";
  font-size: 25px;
  float: right;
}

.active::after {
  content: "\2212";
  color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
}

.panel {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: azure;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  opacity:0; 
}
.acordeon.active + .panel{
  opacity:1;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Acordeon menu</h1>
<button id="acordeon" class="acordeon"></button>
<div id="panel" class="panel">
  <p class="panel--text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ex, architecto dolorem aut molestias aliquam vel fuga repudiandae in labore nobis ut
    eius quasi omnis, ducimus blanditiis placeat sapiente dolore possimus!
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: можете обьяснить подробнее о логике ".acordeon.active + .panel", не совсем понимаю как это работает) А так, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Даная связка срабатывает только когда у `button` будет класс `active` более подробно можно почитать тут - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator